# Snowflake:Flyway:ERROR:Unable to determine Original Schema for the Connection

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flyway

**Requirement:** To run flyway snowflake DB scripts in MacOS

Installed `brew install flyway`

Error: Below screenshot, works fine in Windows machine

[image]

Comment: What JDK are you using on macOS?

Comment: @Sergiu 

```
java --version                                                                                                                    
openjdk 19 2022-09-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 19)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 19, mixed mode, sharing)```

```echo $JAVA_HOME                                                                                                                   /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/19/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Are you using same JDK version on the Windows machine?

Comment: Windows machine ,
$ flyway-9.1.3/jre/bin/java -version
openjdk version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.16+8 (build 11.0.16+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.16+8 (build 11.0.16+8, mixed mode)

 but they dont use `brew install flyway` its only for MacOS

Comment: I know brew is only for macOS, my point was if you use same JDK version, it seems you're using JDK11 on Windows. Can you try same JDK on macOS? I do believe this is an issue caused by the JDK version.

Comment: @Sergiu I tried installing jdk11 , still same issue

Comment: Can you try switching the resultset format from Arrow (default) to JSON? It can be done via Snowflake UI like this: **ALTER USER <youruser> SET JDBC_QUERY_RESULT_FORMAT='JSON';** and then try again to run flyway.

Comment: Yes I tried that too , it didn't work out , so i tried alternate way, will update the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried an alternate way

- Uninstalled `brew uninstall flyway`
- Downloaded Java12 from the Oracle site and installed
- Downloaded flyway tar file and installed